# React, mobx. Не работает mobx с другими библиотеками

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Вот пример кода

```
export default withSnackbar(withStyles(styles)(observer(withTranslation()(PushForm))));
```

Тут mobx не работает.

А без withTranslation он работает

```
withSnackbar(withStyles(styles)(observer(PushForm)))
```

Comment: ```withSnackbar(withStyles(styles)(withTranslation()(observer(PushForm))));```

Comment: Спасибо. А как вы узнали что это работает? Я имею ввиду как это прочитать? В документации не написано что возвращает к примеру withStyles, observer, pushForm